# ImportError: No module named appengine.ext

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models

I am new to Google appengine and django , While I am running my simple sample django on appengine project I got this error,

> ImportError: No module named appengine.ext

From some sources it is found that there is some path issue, but no article says how to set the paths.

Comment: How are you trying to run it?

Comment: I see Windows examples of how to set the path, but none for Mac.

Comment: @jon Mitten , I worked around different solutions the easiest i found for ubuntu is virtualenv as quoted below. It worked for me in ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/)? If not that is a good place to start for setting up your environment (and thus your paths) for your project.

To install the first use:

pip install virtualenv

or

easy_install virtualenv

Then setup the virtualenv wrapper. After you have a virtualenv setup, then install all your libraries and python packages into your new environment via either easy_install, or pip.

Comment: Thank you, sry for late reply. your post is help full thanks once again